# list.FindAll() or list.Where()?

Tags: c#, linq

What are the differences between

```
list.FindAll(c=>c.Contains('@')).Select(c=>new MailAddress(c))
```

and

```
list.Where(c=>c.Contains('@')).Select(c=>new MailAddress(c))
```

and which one should be prefered under which circumstances?

Comment: `FindAll` is a method of `List<T>` and was added in C# 2.0. LINQ is newer and `Where` makes more sense for general `IEnumerable`s. As a byproduct of that - FindAll isn't lazy either.

Comment: According to MSDN `.FindAll` is a method for `List<T>` whereas .Where is for Enumerables

Comment: Also the difference is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989214/list-findall-or-list-where

Comment: Try to use the search, show what you have found and explain what exactly what you want to know that wasn't answered there.